# SQL Server Calculating difference of two dbtimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the dbtime difference. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Declare @StartTime as Date
Declare @FinishTime as Date

set @StartTime = (select dbtime from table1
                  where detail like 'started:Jan 31 2019')

set @FinishTime = (select dbtime from table1
                   where detail like 'finished. Jan 31 2019')

select datediff(ss, @StartTime, @FinishTime) as ExecutionTime
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What database are you using?  Are the values wrong?  Your question doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Using DATE instead of DATETIME? what is exact error message?

Comment: You've defined your variables to be of type `DATE` - which is **just the DATE** - no time portion. So you cannot really get a difference in seconds  from these.... use `DATETIME2(0)` instead - **IF** the `dbtime` column in your `table1` is of type `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` as well

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_ is not really a question, cause we don't know what is the datatypes there, we don't know if you get an error or what's happening, or even if it give you a wrong results. Please read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: The error message would be something along the lines of "the datepart value ss is invalid for datatype date". You need  to change the datatypes to datetime,

Comment: Since `declare @Start as Date = '2010-01-01', @End as Date = '2010-01-02'; select DateDiff( second, @Start, @End );` works, are you trying to get a difference that exceeds the size of an [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? Or is this something completely different like a subquery returning more than one value? Aside: you can use `select @StartTime = dbtime from table1 where detail like 'started:Jan 31 2019';` instead of a `set`. You can retrieve multiple values from a single query as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with DATETIME types.

And the selects for those variables should only return only 1 value.
F.e. by using MAX, MIN or a TOP 1 & ORDER BY.

```
declare @StartTime DATETIME;
declare @FinishTime DATETIME;
declare @SecondsBetweenStartAndFinish INT;

set @StartTime = (select MAX(dbtime) from table1
                  where detail like 'started%Jan 31 2019%');

set @FinishTime = (select MAX(dbtime) from table1
                   where detail like 'finished%Jan 31 2019%');

set @SecondsBetweenStartAndFinish = datediff(second, @StartTime, @FinishTime);

select @SecondsBetweenStartAndFinish as ExecutionTime;
```